# How do I find the volume of this box?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, approximation

I have data points that define the ground and a cubic piece of Styrofoam. the piece of Styrofoam has a cubic ***hole*** cut into it. I need to approximate the volume of the ***hole***.

[image]

I specifically want to do something like calculating the volume contributed by each data point, but from the center outwards. Once the iterative calculations reach the inner edges of the hole, it should stop calculating. How can I do this?

`data2` is of the form `{{x1,y1,z1},{x2,y2,z2},{x3,y3,z3}...}`.

Comment: How do you distinguish between *nothingness* and *Styrofoam*? If you do this by pointing at the z-dimension (i.e. height), then would we assume the height of the hole to be the z-value of the edges?

Comment: @gwr yep, we use z-value to distinguish. From the center outwards we have: the middle of the hole, the top of the Styrofoam, and then the ground.

Comment: I need to find the volume of only the hole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can define the region you can use `NIntegrate`. As a simple example

```
NIntegrate[1, {x, y} ∈ Circle[]]
```

> 6.28319

Here `1` means $\int1 dx dy$ and you get $2 \pi$ (as expected). You can any use other function if you want.

You can define your own region like

```
region = MeshRegion[{{0, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0}, {2, 2, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {1, 1, 2}},
            {Tetrahedron[{1, 2, 3, 5}], Tetrahedron[{1, 3, 4, 5}]}];

HighlightMesh[region, 0]
```

[image]

```
NIntegrate[1, {x, y, z} ∈ region]
```

> 2.66667

Look for [`MeshRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshRegion.html), [`ImplicitRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImplicitRegion.html) and [`ParametricRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricRegion.html) for how to define the mesh.